# PAS instance won't start on Progress Developer Studio

Tags: web-applications, openedge, progress-4gl

I have Progress Developer Studio and I'm learning how to build web apps with Kendo UI Builder.

I have my PAS instance ( with nothing on it ) and it starts up without problems.

When I create a new project ( web app project ) and select the pas instance where it needs to be deployed to, the PAS instance breaks.

'failed to deploy to web app' error.

[image]

Any one here know how to help me?

Thanks

Comment: Is there anything in the workspaces .metadata/.log file?

Comment: What's under the details button?

Answer (score 0):

You screenshot looks like 11.6. Try 11.7 - there's the free class room edition available at https://www.progress.com/openedge/classroom-edition